# Adding email/password firebase login in Polymer Starter Kit app

Tags: javascript, firebase, polymer-1.0, firebase-authentication

I've been trying to add simple email / password signup/login for Firebase to the [Polymer Starter Kit](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/todo-list) app. It comes stock with a Google auth sign in via a single button but there doesn't seem to be any instructions on how to set-up email/password register/login instead.

Here is the specific part of the code from the project's `todo-auth.html` file  I've been struggling with:

```
    <firebase-auth id="authenticate"
                   user="{{user}}"
                   location="{{location}}"
                   ref="{{refauth}}"
                   provider="">
    </firebase-auth>

    <paper-dialog modal
                  opened="[[!user]]"
                  entry-animation="scale-up-animation"
                  exit-animation="fade-out-animation">
      <h2>Please sign in</h2>
      <div>

        <!-- Inputs I added to accept user credentials -->
            <paper-input id="loginEmailInput"
                         no-label-float
                         label="Email"
                         on-keydown="">
            </paper-input>
                  <paper-input id="loginPasswordInput"
                         no-label-float
                         label="Password"
                         on-keydown="">
            </paper-input>

            <paper-button on-tap="logIn">Login</paper-button>


<!-- Original Google sign-in code --> 
<!--         <div class="google-sign-in"
             tabindex="0"
             on-tap="signIn">
          <span class="google-sign-in-icon"></span>
          <span class="google-sign-in-label">Google</span>
        </div> -->
      </div>
    </paper-dialog>
```

I removed `google` from the `provider` property of the `<firebase-auth>` element and added a couple of input fields but don't really know where to go from there.

Here is the Polymer script part of todo-auth.html

```
  <script>
    Polymer({

      is: 'todo-auth',

      properties: {

        user: {
          notify: true
        }

      },

      logIn: function() {
        this.$.authenticate.login();
      },

      signOut: function() {
        this.$.authenticate.logout();
        this.user = null;
      }
    });

  </script>
```

I've tried to find examples or guide tutorials on how to implement this but everything I've found has used the google based auth as login. Likewise, all other questions I've found here on SO have focused on google login.

I'd be grateful for any directions or pointers or tutorials on how to set it up. Thanks all in advance!

**UPDATE**

I managed to implement a new page with a form using the demo from the [Google Web Components github rep](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/firebase-element/blob/master/demo/x-login.html)o.

I have a `my-firebase.html` file that imports everything I can think of to make it work. Imports look like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-auth.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-app.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymerfire/polymerfire.html">
```

I have also added the following for `firebase-app` and `firebase-auth`:

```
<firebase-app auth-domain="my-polymer-app.firebaseapp.com"
      database-url="https://my-polymer-app.firebaseio.com/"
      api-key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
</firebase-app>
<firebase-auth id="firebaseLogin" user="{{user}}" status-known="{{statusKnown}}" location="my-polymer-app.firebaseapp.com" provider="{{provider}}" on-error="errorHandler" on-user-created="userSuccessHandler" on-password-changed="us erSuccessHandler" on-password-reset="userSuccessHandler" on-user-removed="userSuccessHandler"></firebase-auth>
```

I am now getting the following error when I try to login(I have already set up a user in my Firebase App to test):

```
my-firebase.html:122 Uncaught TypeError: this.$.firebaseLogin.login is not a function
```

Which refers to this part of the code take from the Google Web Components repo.

```
login: function() {
      var params;

      try {
        params = JSON.parse(this.params);
      } catch (e) {
        params = null;
      }

      if (this.provider == 'password') {
        params = params || {};
        params.email = this.email;
        params.password = this.password;
      }

      this.$.firebaseLogin.login(params);
    }
```

There are also red boxes around every instance of `firebaseLogin` on the page. No other errors are showing up so not sure what this means exactly. Again, I'd be grateful if anyone could point out what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Use signInWithEmailAndPassword function instead of login function,

```
this.$.firebaseLogin.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password);
```